# Python: put numbers into list

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
    1 acatccacgg atgaaggaga ggagaaatgt ttcaaatcag ttctaacacg aaaaccaatt
   61 ccaagaccaa gttatgaaat taccactaag cagcagtgaa agaactacat attgaagtca
  121 gataagaaag caagctgaag agcaagcact gggcatcttt cttgaaaaaa gtaaggccca
  181 agtaacagac tatcagattt ttttgcagtc tttgcattcc tactagatga ttcacagaga
  241 agatagtcac atttatcatt cgaaaacatg aaagaattcc agtcagaact tgcatttggg
  301 ggcatgtaag tctcaaggtt gtctttttgc caatgtgctg taacattatt gcactcagag
  361 tgtactgctg acagccactg ttctgccgaa atgacagaaa atagggaaca
```

I am trying to read the txt file and make a dictionary that puts the text information into a dictionary like this: {1:[acatccacgg,atgaaggaga, ggagaaatgt, ttcaaatcag, ttctaacacg, aaaaccaatt], 61 : ...} 
I have no clue how to do this...I am really new to python

Comment: you could probably use re(regular expressions), I will post the answer several minutes later, because i have done the similar projects too.

Comment: Yeah, `re` is probably the best way to go

Comment: But if you are trying to read the text file then check out this website https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

Comment: If I don't miss something reading in the file line by line and splitting by whitespace should allow you to do what you want.
The number is always the first field in the line?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this line of code.

```
f = open('test.txt','r')
mydictionary = {}
for x in f:
    temp = x.strip().split(' ')
    mydictionary.update({temp[0]:temp[1:]})
f.close()
print(mydictionary)
```

Comment: If you're reading from a file, `x` will be a `str`. No need for `str(x)`…

Answer (score -1):

this is  the cleaner, and more readable way to do so (just try it, and you will understand):

```
import re
from os.path import exists


def put_in_dict(directory: str):
     """With this function you can find the digits's in every line and
     then put it in keys and then you can put the character's in the same line
     as value to that key."""
    my_dict = {}
    pattern_digit = re.compile(r"\d+")
    pattern_char = re.compile(r"\w+")
    char = []
    if exists(directory):
        with open(f"{directory}") as file:
             all_text = file.read().strip()

        list_txt = all_text.splitlines()
        numbs = pattern_digit.findall(all_text)

        for num in range(len(list_txt)):
            char.append(pattern_char.findall(list_txt[num]))
            del char[num][0]

        for dict_set in range(len(numbs)):
            my_dict[numbs[dict_set]] = char[dict_set]

    return my_dict  # you could make it print(my_dict) too
```